# Linux timestamp to PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

I have the following timestamp:

```
1342259667654
```

which when converted with http://www.epochconverter.com/ gives:

```
Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
GMT: Sat, 14 Jul 2012 09:54:27 GMT
Your time zone: 14. juli 2012 11:54:27 GMT+2
```

And that is the correct time, but when using:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1342259667654);
```

I get the following date:

```
1904-07-24 10:22:47
```

How can I get with PHP the exact date out of this time stamp?

Comment: you want current date or what?

Comment: Just removing the last 3 chars gave me the right result? i.e. 1342259667

Comment: DERP... its because that timestamp is milliseconds, PHP date() uses seconds, so you need to divide by 1000

Comment: Your timestamp has too much digits in it. `1342259667654` has `13` digits, while the current timestamp, `1342296092` only has `10`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your timestamp needs to be divided by 1000:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1342259667654/1000);
```

Comment: Thank you @davidethell, missed that part.

Answer (score 2):

```
$timestamp = 1342259667; 
$dt = new DateTime("@$timestamp");  // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can also do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The value `1342259667654` is actually in miliseconds, while PHP's `date()` function is unable to handle miliseconds value. Hence the weird output.